# Permutation and Set of Numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Given the following set of numbers: {3,6,7,8,9,10,12,15,18}

How many 4 distinct members of the above set are there such that when added result in a sum less than or equal to 26?

Is there a fast way of doing this rather than checking all of them by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use $3$, your sum will be $\ge 5+7+8+9>26$, so you must use $3$.
If you don't use $6$ next, your sum will be $\ge 3+7+8+9>26$, so you must use $6$.
So you are left with picking two numbers from $\{7,8,9,10,12,15,18\}$ with sum $\le 17$. Without $7$, you can only take $8+9$. With $7$, you can take any of $\{8,9,10\}$ as last number.

Answer (score 1):

Checking by hand is probably best in this case, because there are so few valid picks. Sum of 26 means an average of 6.5, so you can't really pick any of the large ones: $3,6,7,10$ is already at the limit, so really, 10 is the biggest number available, not 18.

If you instead wanted, say, a sum of $38$, it would be more work, but I still think brute force counting would be best. But be systematic: split into cases depending on what the largest (or smallest, if you want) number is, then solve the simplified problem of picking three numbers from a smaller list with a smaller bound for the sum. And if you want, you can split each of those into cases again. It is less work than it seems.